# Put add-ons to new EE site

Tags: add-on, ee3

EE novice here, if I download the free version of an EE site, can I still download paid add-ons to the free version and have them function without problems?

Comment: Yes. Everything should work!

Comment: Comparison of versions: https://store.ellislab.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you won't have any issues. Having a free version of EE won't affect paid plugins working. Free EE just limits what you can do inside it's core features I believe

Answer (score 0):

Using paid add-ons with EE Core poses no technical problems. The technically imposed limitations are noted here: https://store.ellislab.com/#ee-core

Also note that the major limitation of EE Core is what the license agreement allows you to do with it.